# Access Global variable from IconItemRenderer

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

Is it possible to use a global variable defined in app.mxml within the myIconFunction defined below ?

```
<s:List id="list" x="7" y="10" width="463" height="661"
        creationComplete="list_creationCompleteHandler(event)" labelField="name" click="list_clickHandler(event)">
    <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <s:IconItemRenderer  labelField="name"
                                 iconFunction="myIconFunction"

                                decorator="@Embed(source='assets/images/general/arrow_next.jpg')"
                                 iconWidth="50"
                                 iconHeight="50">
                <fx:Script>
                    <![CDATA[
                        private function myIconFunction(item:Object):String
                        {
                            return "http://localhost/mydatapath/" + item.imagelink;
                           // how to use this.parentApplication.dataPath here
                        }
                    ]]>
                </fx:Script>
            </s:IconItemRenderer>
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>

</s:List>
```

The parentApplication.dataPath variable stores IP of my server. Since I have used similar functions at several places in my application, it requires me to change the IP at every place when I move from localhost to actual server. 
Using

```
 this.parentApplication.dataPath + item.imagelink
```

gives compile time error. 
So is it possible to use an external/global variable within such a function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by making the myIconFunction public

```
public function myIconFunction(item:Object):String
                    {
                        return this.parentApplication.dataIP + item.imagelink;
                       // works
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you're using your main Application as a model repository, I'd go for a model contained in other place (probably a singlenton or an injected instance). Anyways,  `FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication` contains a reference to your main Application.

Comment: thanks, but I solved the problem in an alternate way. +1 for suggestion on design.

Comment: Glad to see you solve your issue :). Also, I would refactor/extract that function to a proper place: i.e. an utility class. Your item renderer shouldn't know anything about your configuration, it only wants to render an icon. An improved mechanism could be the following: `ServerConfigurationUtils.completeURL(item.imagelink)` and the declaration of ServerConfigurationUtils would contain a reference to your model repository, that in completeURL concats the `dataIP` with the item `imagelink`.